# Getting RSSI value in a laptop with Windows installed

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

How can I get the RSSI value through my laptop that has Windows XP installed?

I need to read RSSI value through any computer with a wireless card that is receiving packets from a nearby access point. I need to get it without using a specific software that reads it. A C or Java code is a possible solution.

Comment: windows has nothing native. With work on the question it could be migrated to stackoverflow with a tag of C or java. Though they won't be too happy about somebody asking them to code something, so would have to be quite a different question.

Comment: I think what you're looking for might be a portable (i.e.: self-contained EXE that can be run from a USB stick) wardriving tool.  I'm not aware of any, but maybe someone else here can point you in the right direction.